# How can I import my JSON file in to app.ts to display the options in app.html?

Tags: html, angular

How can I import my Json file in to app.ts to display the options in app.html?

```js
//This is my app.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
//This is my Json file it is located in Assets folder
[
 {"firstName" : "Samudrala", "lastName": "Raamu"},
 {"firstName" : "Samudrala", "lastName": "Raamu"},
 {"firstName" : "Samudrala", "lastName": "Raamu"},
 {"firstName" : "Samudrala", "lastName": "Raamu"},
 {"firstName" : "Samudrala", "lastName": "Raamu"},
 {"firstName" : "Samudrala", "lastName": "Raamu"},
 {"firstName" : "Samudrala", "lastName": "Raamu"},
 {"firstName" : "Samudrala", "lastName": "Raamu"}
]
```

```html
<!--This is app.html-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<select>
<option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
results : any =[];
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.getJSON().subscribe(data => results=data, error => console.log(error));
 }

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("./yourJson.json")
                         .map((res:any) => res)
                         .catch((error:any) => console.log(error));
}
```

and then use ngFor

```
 <select  [(ngModel)]="secondSelectValue" >
    <option *ngFor="let opt of results" [value]="opt">
      {{ opt }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: you need to import httpClientModule